# Django using PostgreSQL - duplicated indexes

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-models, indexing

I'm using `Django` over `PostgreSQL`, and I'm having trouble understanding how to use indices correctly to achieve the best performance. This is an example Model:

```
class SomeObject(BaseAggModel):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    element = models.ForeignKey(Element, on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_index=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_index=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('element', 'city', 'date_created')
        
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['city ', 'element'])
        ]
```

My questions are regarding how to change the indices to have as few indices as possible but maintain the best performance possible.

Since I have the `unique_together`, and `element` is the first entity in that index. Does it necessarily mean that I can change the `element` field to have `db_index=False` since I already have a combined index to this field?

Since I have the index over `city` and `element` together, and `city` is the first entity in this index. Does it necessarily mean I can change the `city` field to have `db_index=False` since I probably don't need a dedicated index for it?

Alternatively (instead of doing the previous changes mentioned), since I have the `unique_together` and also the `Index`. If I will reorder the `unique_together` to be over `(city, element, date_created)`, will it make the index over `(city, element)` redundant and can be deleted without hurting performance?

Comment: What are the common queries that you run in the model (what fields do you query by)? You should tailor your indexes around your queries

Comment: Assuming that no index here is completely redundant (used for some queries) I'm wondering whether having one index on pair completely adheres the index on a single entity useless. If not - why and how can I see that

Comment: Well the indexes on the ForeignKey fields are redundant since ForeignKey fields are always indexed anyway

Comment: You most likely only need one index that spans your multiple columns, order it from least unique column to most unique (column that has the most repeated values to column that has the least repeated values) and you should be good

Comment: I don't have precise answers for this, but these Postgres docs explain related questions: [multicolumn indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/indexes-multicolumn.html) and [combining multiple indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/indexes-bitmap-scans.html).

Answer (score 0):

The question of indexes cannot be de-correlated to the queries thats users will execute. There is no possibility with a magic crystal ball to know in advance what the queries will be. So the creation and deletion of indexes is a real DBA job, and must be done on a regular basis, as an example, every 3 months.
Some RDBMS gives information about missing indexes that they have detected to be relevant, for some queries... This is the case in Microsoft SQL Server since version 2005. Also you need to have a view that count access in time to all indexes to know if an index is really used. Sometimes indexes were used frequently and then become obsolete since a release of the product have change the ways of operations are executed.
So, in what I call an "indexing campaign", regularly done, you must drop unused indexes and create new indexes based upon real world exploitation...